# how to refresh a long SQ source qualifier object from the altered source definition

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Don't seem to find an easy method to refresh a source-qualifier when the linked source definition has been refreshed from the database. Specifically, if the SQ is rather large, and its outgoing links are a-many, which presents a laborious option if doing this manually (during database upgrades, for instance).

Any ideas?

- Saving and checking in the source definition, correctly sets mapping to "needs validation" state - check.
- Target definitions get refreshed, shortcuts - get refreshed from both the source defs and target defs - check.
- SQ object - doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag the source again from Object Browser window. This will autogenerate SQ for the Source. So the SQ will be in sync with Source - but there is no easy way to reconnect all the links back.

You can use Autolink option to help you out. There's an option to define Prefixes or Suffixes if needed. This helps a lot, but won't solve everyting if you've got some more sophisticated links.